# Upload mp3 file not working in codeigniter

Tags: file-upload, mp3, codeigniter-3

I am trying to upload mp3 file into folder using codeigniter V3.1.8 but i get error when i trying to upload any .mp3 file. I got "**The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.**" error.

Here is my controller, view code.

CommonController.php

```
public function uploadSong( $ref_id ) {
    $status = $url = "";
    $data['user_info']                  = $this->data;
    if ($status != "error") {
        $config['upload_path']          = './assets/songs/';
        $url                                = 'assets/songs/';
    }

    $config['allowed_types']                = 'mp3';
    $config['max_size']                     = 99999;
    //$config['encrypt_name']               = TRUE;
    //chmod('assets/', 0777);
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('file_name')) {
        $status                     = 'error';
        $msg                        = $this->upload->display_errors('', '');
        echo $msg;
    } else {
        // Go ahead

    }
}
```

upload.php

```
      <?php echo form_open_multipart(base_url() . 'upload-song/'.$song[0]['id']);?>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Select Song</label>
              <input type="file" name="file_name" size="20" required="true" />
           </div>
           <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" id="submit" value="Upload" />
      <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

config/mimes.php

```
 'mp3'  =>  array('audio/mpeg', 'audio/mpg', 'audio/mpeg3', 'audio/mp3'),
```

Same process do with images upload and its working fine but am not getting what's going wrong with mp3 upload. Any idea whats going wrong with my code ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to replace in config/mimes.php from,

```
'mp3'  =>  array('audio/mpeg', 'audio/mpg', 'audio/mpeg3', 'audio/mp3'),
```

to,

```
'mp3'   => array('video/mp3', 'application/octet-stream', 'audio/mpeg', 'audio/mpg', 'audio/mpeg3', 'audio/mp3'),
```

Now it's working fine.